# How to write a guitar string code in Python?

Tags: python, vpython, guitar, sound-synthesis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guitar string code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731726/guitar-string-code-in-python)

I'm really interested in making a code that could simulate guitar strings. How would I go about doing this? Or at least how would I begin to do this?

Here are my ideas:

I would like to see the sound waves (to analyze the amplitudes and frequencies)when playing different strings, notes, etc. I am also interested in the sound waves when two different strings are being played, and how that changes when they are dissonant and consonant notes. Another thing I'm interested in is how sometimes strings vibrate when they are not being plucked (resonance).

I just need a base code that I can make changes to, but I have no clue how to make one.

Thank you!!